# Inline image height equal to font height

Tags: css

I have an image that represents my email address.  I want that this image has the same height as font height or line height.  So I tried this:

```
img.address { height: 1em; width: auto }

<p>My e-mail address is <img class="address" height="15" width="149" src="address.png" alt="[]" />.</p>
```

It seems to work for Chrome on desktop, but for Chrome on smartphone image is much smaller than the font.  I don't understand why?  Is there any remedy for that?

NOTE: since this method works for desktop browser, the question could be rephrased like this: **why is in smartphone browsers the height of the font not `1em` and how can one obtain the height of the font?**

**EDIT:** I added few commands around the image to put it into the context.

Comment: it will differ as your mobile probably have a smaller font-size then used on your image. In order to make this work you would have to check what your `font-size` is in mobile and try to make the height of the image to reflect what seems to be correct. *note:* height of your image does not nessesary mean it's the same as your `font-size`. If possible you would save a lot of headache by not having a image trying to match font-sizes, or have 2/3 versions to match your font-size.

Comment: @Dejan.S Actually it is the image that is too small on the mobile.  Also, `1em` is supposed to be the font height.  This is what makes this problem really mysterious.

Comment: I can't find the "email" image you have issues with? For your own help it would benefit if you answer some of my questions in my answer.

Comment: @Pygmalion - I am glad to see I'm not the only one facing this dilemma, and that solving is not so straightforward. In my case it was just trying to support older browsers that can't do emojis via codes, using a collection of old school graphics. With responsive design i am finding it tough. Since I let my fonts scale by declaring them as % of the main <head> and <html> size of 1 rem, no image scaling by ems or rems has worked consistently. Best approximation I've been able to do is find a graphic width that works by % (might be small, like 4%), and then re-scale in my media queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default font-size for a webpage is 16px ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)) where no more setting is applied on document. You didn't set any font size to your html or body or paragraphs and so:

- the browser renders image by default font-size (16px) because there
  is no more setting to control images size.
- Text of webpage may not use default 16px for many other overriding settings as well as android initial settings, accessibility options, mobile friendly standards to render texts etc.

So you have to define your desired font size for entire document and then the texts and images height will have same reference.

Finally if you dont want to set initial font size, a javascript trick is to calculate the height of rendered lines and set it as image height. For example I suggest to extract first word from text and put it into a temporary `div` and after calculating the height of that div, set it as image height:

```
var myhtml=$('#imageId').parent().text();
var mywords=myhtml.split(" ");
var fisrtWord=mywords[0];
$(body).append('<div id="tempdiv">' + firstword + '</div>');
$('#imageId').height($('#tempdiv').heigh());
$('#tempdiv').remove();
```

Final note: the height of lines is about 1.5 times taller than the characters height. So you may reduce the calculated height by 1.5 to have better result.

Comment: I am reluctant to define the font size, with hundreds of different screen sizes.  I rather rely on browser designers to do a good job and keep the default.

Comment: As I mentioned above, there are many external options to control text sizes where there are fewer options to control image sizes. So you can not rely only on the default font-size of the browser when using `em` unit.

Comment: In other words, for the problem that I posed there is no solution?

Comment: I think the css is not enough. I added a jquery trick to calculate the height of rendered lines.

Comment: OK, have no expirience in jquery, and no experience how to use javascript with css.  I will study the solution and try to implement it.

Comment: If I understood it right, you put some text in, measure it and remove it.  Of course, I could put such div permanently around existing paragraph and just measure the text with one-liner?  I am also unsure how to pass that information to css.

Comment: To make it easier, here is the snippet from my HTML: `<p>My email address is <img class="address" height="15" width="149" src="address.png" alt="[]" /></p>`

Comment: My code is enough to pass the size to email image. Just give the image and id and use that id instead of `imageId` in my code. Do not forget to include jquery before my code.

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you for the idea.  I wrote a pure JavaScript version.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually it is the image that is too small on the mobile. Also, 1em is
>   supposed to be the font height. This is what makes this problem really
>   mysterious.

Well not really. `font-size: 16px;` does not equal to `height: 16px;`. `line-height: 16px;` will not either, it actually "just" adds space on top and bottom of the chars. The `font-size` actually is the width of the widest character in the alphabet (I think it actually measure the letter M). So the thing you are trying to do won't work. Then there is the fact that you would have to cut the image *exactly* with no space, meaning there is a possible error source there. You would have to try to set the height manually by measure and compare in different viewports. If you give me a hint of what you are trying to do with a screen or something I could possibly present you a other solution. Is there a reason why you want to use a image for your email and not a regular html?

Comment: OK I recognise that `1em` is not exactly a measure of character height, but it is a good approximation.  Anyways, at my mobile phone in portrait mode the picture height is about a third or a quarter of character size, so there must be something wrong.  If I figure out how to share that with you, I shall do it.

Comment: I am sorry for a late reply, I was very busy lately.  I want to protect my e-mail from mail scraping.  And figure seems to be rather simple solution.